# Is RAM expandable for Hp Compaq 15-s103TX

Tags: laptop, memory

I would like to buy this laptop
[HP Cpmpaq 15-s103TX](http://www.flipkart.com/hp-compaq-15-s103tx-notebook-4th-gen-ci3-4gb-1tb-free-dos-2gb-graph-k8t82pa/p/itmefwhzp3u664bg?pid=COMEFWHHGDBH7UUG)

According to specs, RAM seems to be expandable upto 8 GB. But in the Memoty section, unused slots is 0. Does this mean, if I wish to expand memory, do I have to remove one of the filled slot and replace it with the new memory module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no available slots you will have to remove the existing ram and replace it. Ideally you should match ram modules with similar ram. Example: 4GB + 4GB = 8. Other than size, you should also consider the speed of the module. If you pair modules of different speeds, the faster will clock down to match the slower.